# Did I hear rightly – “Shiite Houthis are stated in to return the President to office.”

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, pronunciation

The answer would be very likely "No."

I’ve been listening to AP Radio news, and heard the news of May 15 reporting the outcome of cease-fire negotiation between Saudi-led forces and Shiite Houthis as follows:.

> “The problem is the talks are not happening in Yemen. They are in
>   Saudi Arabia, which just happen to be leading a coalition launching
>   air-strikes on the rebels, who’ve taken over Yemen’s capital and sent
>   the President packing. So the Shiite Houthis rebels aren’t interested
>   in the U.N.-led talks, nor they are **stated (in / realm?)** to return the
>   President to office.”

I’m not clear with the last line, “nor they are (stated in / realm) to return the President to office.” It doesn’t seem to make sense to me. I suspect I heard it wrongly.

Though I regret absence of my knowledge to include actual voice of the news in this question, could you suggest any words that sound similar to “stated in /realm” and would fit here?

Comment: Is this from a transcript? Can you give a link to the transcript or audio? It's hard to know what is meant by 'stated (in / realm)'. Did they say both 'in' and 'realm'? Is that an approximation to what you heard or what was actually typed originally. As is, you're right, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mitch. We have been listening AP Radio News through Eagle 10 - Far East Network together with members of local English speaking society. This is a transcript of the news I heard at 9:00 am Myay 15 here in Tokyo area. The part in question sounds something like “Now they are ‘stated in’ to return the President to office,” or “Now they are ‘stated realm’ to return the President to office,” I don't have a link.In either ways, it doesn’t make sense to me. I wonder what did announcer actually read out the script.

Comment: Please don't tag question with `words` that tag is meaningless. I actually went through ten posts yesterday retagging. I mean, what does `words` mean? Instead `word-choice`, and  `word-usage` are more descriptive.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. I erased "words" tag.  I just want to know rightly fitting words.

Comment: He might have said "slated (in)".  This can mean planned or scheduled.  See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slated    (sense 3 under **vb(tr)**)

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock. I suspected it could be “slated” first. I replayed the line in question again and again. But the voice sounds “stated in” with clear sound of “t,” not “l.” Even accepting “slated,” “in” is unnecessary before “to return the President.” I started to think the AP news announcer misread the text, though it’s unusual.

Comment: Yoichi-san, since you "replayed the line", it would be really helpful to give a relevant link in the question so that others could do the same.

Comment: @Andrew Leach. I replayed the line in question of the passage recorded in the tape. I wish I could record the news in digital  media and upload it in the site. But I'm a total idiot in handling pc. However, Gaurav's anser seems very plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally random guess, but what about "nor *their stated aim is* to return the president to power"?

Comment: @Gaurave.I mistyped "now" for "nor" (It sounds so) . So I edited the corresponding word in your answer so.

Answer (score 0):

SLATED IS THE WORD means scheduled verb oxford dictionary,  I use it all the time I have used it for years quite surprised no one here is familiar with it.

Comment: Hello, Susi, and welcome to EL&U. As written, your answer seems a bit haphazard. Certainly, _slated_ sounds similar to _stated_, but—given that (as you say) _slated_ has the primary meaning "scheduled"—it doesn't sound very suitable as a fill-in-the-blank answer for the phrase "Shiite Houythis are _______ to return the President to office." After all, the quoted paragraph is about a lack of talks (and other planning) between the hostile forces in Yemen. You might strengthen your answer by explaining why _slated_ is an appropriate word to use here anyway. Thanks!